# Integrate Qt VS tools with vcpkg-installed qt

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-10, qt5, qt-vs-addin

**Platform**: Visual Studio 2017 / Qt 5.11 / vcpkg 2018.10.20-nohash / Windows 10 1803 64

I have installed the qt5 library using vcpkg `./vcpkg install qt5:x64-windows`

Under `${vcpkg_root}/installed/x64-windows/tools`, there are 6 sub-directories:

1. qt5: holds 2 conf files qt_release.conf and qt_debug.conf having the following structure:

   [Paths]
   Prefix = ${CURRENT_INSTALLED_DIR}
   Documentation = share/qt5/doc
   Headers = include
   Libraries = debug/lib
   Binaries = debug/tools/qt5
   LibraryExecutables = debug/tools/qt5
   Plugins = debug/plugins
   Qml2Imports = debug/qml
   Data = share/qt5/debug
   ArchData = share/qt5/debug
   HostData = share/qt5/debug
   HostBinaries = tools/qt5
2. qt5-3d, qt5-declarative, qt5-scxml, qt5-tools, and qt5-xmlpatterns which all have an empty qt.conf file

I tried to add all the possible paths in the "Add New Qt Version" of the Qt VS Tools, each time I get the error:

`${SPECIFIED_PATH}/bin/qmake.exe is not found`.
qmake.exe is directly under qt5 directory, there is no bin/ sub-directory.

```
.\qmake.exe -v
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.11.2 in C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/tools/qt5/${CURRENT_INSTALLED_DIR}/debug/lib
```

I also considered adding bin/ subdirectory and moving qmake.exe there, however I found that multiple other issues would arise when I read this thread https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues/2643.

How to integrate the qt library to the QtVSTools correctly ?

Comment: I've the same issue. Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: No, I switched to the MinGW toolchain.